# Use SAS to display percentages on graphs

Tags: sas

I have a SAS data table with two columns. One is about the age of a person and another about the religion of a person:

```
id    Age    Religion
 1    10      Catholic
 2    11      Catholic
 3    12      Christian
 4    13      Christian
 5    11      Muslim
 6    12      Catholic
 7    .....
 8 ......
```

In SAS, I need to display a graph showing for each age the percentage of people belonging to each religion. Does any one knows how to do this?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried first. Try PROC FREQ and make sure to specify the options to include graphs, you'll get a graph by default that should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1) Calculate % of religion within group using **proc freq**

2) Plot the required graph using **proc sgplot**

```
data have;
        input id age religion $20.;
        datalines;
     1    10      Catholic
     2    11      Catholic
     3    12      Christian
     4    13      Christian
     5    11      Muslim
     6    12      Catholic
     7    11      Hindu
    ;
    run;

proc sort data=have;
by age religion;
quit;

proc freq data=have noprint;
by age;                         /* X categories on BY statement */
tables religion / out=have1;    /* Y (stacked groups) on TABLES statement */
run;

proc sgplot data=have1;
title 'Age vs Religion';
vbar age / response=PERCENT group=religion ;
xaxis grid  label='Age';
yaxis grid  label='Percent';
run;
```

Let me know in case you have any doubts.